# Prove that $\sum_{n\leq x}{d(\phi(n))} > x \log{x}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> Prove that $$\sum_{n\leq x}{d(\phi(n))} > x \log{x},$$
>   where $d(n)$ is the number of factors of $n,\phi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function.

From Wikipedia, I know that
$$\phi(n)>\frac{n}{e^\gamma \log{\log{n}}+\frac{3}{\log{\log{n}}}},$$
 for n>2. I wonder how to to continue.

Comment: See https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/Luca_2_3476.pdf,  https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/tauphicorr2.pdf, and http://www.csun.edu/~sungjin/SJK_tauphilambda2.pdf for the progress on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may exploit the fact that *usually* $d(\varphi(n))> d(n)$ (if $p>2$, the totient function maps $p^k$ into $(p-1)p^{k-1}$, which has more divisors) and the fact that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{d(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2 = \frac{1}{(s-1)^2}+\frac{2\gamma}{s-1}+H(s-1) $$
up to a holomorphic function, behaves like $-\zeta'(s)+2\gamma \zeta(s)$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin. This leads to
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}d(k) \approx \log(n)+2\gamma $$
and to the fact that your inequality holds for any $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Are you sure that $d(\phi(n)) > d(n)$? Since $\phi(n) < n$, by iterating this, you a decreasing sequence $n_{i+1} = \phi(n_i)$ with increasing $d(n_i)$.

Comment: @martycohen: I have modified the intro, taking into account the cases like $d(\varphi(2^k))=d(2^k)-1$, which form a minority.